# why to we need to use prompt.start()?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning NodeJs.

The following code has the same affect if I put "prompt.start();" in comment:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

  // 
  // Start the prompt 
  // 


  prompt.start();

  // 
  // Get two properties from the user: username and email 
  // 
  prompt.get(['username', 'email'], function (err, result) {
    // 
    // Log the results. 
    // 
    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  username: ' + result.username);
    console.log('  email: ' + result.email);
  });
```

So what is the meaning of `prompt.start()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the best place to answer questions like this is the [source code itself](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt/blob/master/lib/prompt.js#L68).

If you look at that, you'll see that `start()` has an `options` parameter that you can pass it to configure how things work.

Just above the function is some documentation:

```
//
// ### function start (options)
// #### @options {Object} **Optional** Options to consume by prompt
// Starts the prompt by listening to the appropriate events on `options.stdin`
// and `options.stdout`. If no streams are supplied, then `process.stdin`
// and `process.stdout` are used, respectively.
//
```

Aside from processing the options parameter, there is some code at the end of the function, which (on the surface) could be problematic if you skipped:

```
if (process.platform !== 'win32') {
    // windows falls apart trying to deal with SIGINT
    process.on('SIGINT', function () {
      stdout.write('\n');
      process.exit(1);
    });
  }

  prompt.emit('start');
  prompt.started = true;
  return prompt;
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't going to effect the `get` command in that instance.  It will effect whether or not you can `pause` or `resume` the prompt.  It also allows you to pass options to customize your prompt.